# Projection of a point on a set

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $M=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{3}: x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}\le4, x_{1}^{2}-4x_{2}\le0\}$ and $y=(1,0,2)^{T}$. What is the projection of the vector $y$ on the set $M$?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a projection? You're supposed to solve the following optimization problem:
$$\min \|x - y\|_2,\ x \in M.$$

Comment: ya, but this is a long solution. I am supposed to use a more elegant solution and find the point without any optimalization.